# Corporate internet & viewing a Wix site

Tags: hosting, nameservers, blacklist

Our Wix site is not visible from within a corporate internet but is visible outside it. Would it be correct to assume that the corporate's IT has blocked Wix somehow? (this is what we've been told is likely the issue).

The site is hosted at Wix & has it's domain name managed by Wix (ie. uses WIXDNS.NET as its nameserver)

If this is the case, would changing the registrar solve the issue, or would one need to move both the domain name plus move the hosted content? 
Does blacklisting affect the domain name or hosted content?

TIA

Comment: It can be posted over https://serverfault.com/

Comment: "Would it be correct to assume that the corporate's IT has blocked Wix somehow?" not based on the elements provides, which are empty by the way. You need to add more troubleshooting and use proper forum, as this one is only related to programming questions.  "would changing the registrar solve the issue" probably not. The registrar has no operational part in the day to day DNS resolution (except if it is also the DNS provider, which is a separate role).

Answer (score 1):

There are many variables and techniques that IT can use to block certain websites. It is possible that your company's security settings are looking for certain keywords in URLs, whether that be "wix", or something contained in your website name.

Because you're using a paid domain, it may just be that the IP address of the website is within a blocked range on the company firewall or it is running on a blocked port (more unlikely).